# Need help getting this closure working

Tags: javascript

I'd like to be able to call this function from another function and not use an event handler as in the code below. Instead of element.onclick, I'd like to do something like

```
window.myFunction = (function(){ //the rest of the closure code//}
```

where I can call myFunction(); from another function instead of having to click a button.

```
var element = document.getElementById('button');

element.onclick = (function() {
// init the count to 0
var count = 0;

return function(e) {
    //count
    count++;

    if (count === 3) {
        // do something every third time
        alert("Third time's the charm!");
        //reset counter
        count = 0;
    }
};
})();
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fimoxake/2/edit)**

```
var element = document.querySelector('#button'),
    count = 0;

function myCountFunction(){
   count = ++count % 3; // loop count
   if ( !count ) {      // if count is 0
      alert("Third time's the charm!");
   }
}

//On click:
element.addEventListener('click', myCountFunction, false);


// Immediately:
myCountFunction(); // this will trigger the event once

// Inside some other function: 
function myOtherFunction(){
   myCountFunction();  
}
```

Comment: You made quite a few changes to the original code, good changes nevertheless.  The "immediately" comment is no longer true and misleading at best.  It is not invoked immediately.

Comment: @Khnle by "Immediately" I mean that the function is called after the code is parsed and the DOM is ready. To our eyes... well, *"immediately"*. Not to be confused with or other stuff (IIFE etc...). Thanks for the note though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
var element = document.getElementById('button');

var f = (function() {
    var count = 0;

    return function(e) { //e is not really needed, but left in there anyway
      //count
      count++;

      if (count === 3) {
        // do something every third time
        alert("Third time's the charm!");
        //reset counter
        count = 0;
      }
  };
})();
element.onclick = f;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2eFD2/2/

Comment: Outside of assigning the closure to a variable, can you explain what is different? If its just the variable assignment that fixes the problem, why is that?

Comment: you have an issue in your demo: `<button id="button">Button</div>`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Thanks, I changed </div> to </button>